# How do i perform axios api calls in react without hardcoding localhost:8080

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, routes, axios

I am performing axios calls like this.
Now, When i host this application , i want the port number and the relative path to be configurable and not localhost:8080. How do i achieve this.

Also, i want the api calls to be routed through DNS and not directly.
What is the best approach which is as per the ideal coding practices.

````
axios
                              .post("http://localhost:8080/api/filterData/updateZCDP", ZCDPres)
                              .then((res) => {
                                console.log(res);
                              })
                              .catch((err) => {
                                console.log(err);
                                toast.error("Error in inserting zcdp");
                              });```
````

Comment: Your 2 questions are completely unrelated to each other. For the first, just use a global variable that holds your URL and port or the axios instance that uses `baseURL`. For the second, use `/etc/hosts` if on Linux or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if on Windows.